# Constraint satisfying 3-array of constraints.Float with methods

Tags: go, generics

One of the things I have been looking forward to with Go 1.18's generics is to use a 3-element vector type which can take `float32` or `float64` for its elements. Come today, this is now possible:

```golang
import "golang.org/x/exp/constraints"

type Vec3[T constraints.Float] [3]T

func (vec Vec3[T]) Add(other Vec3[T]) Vec3[T] {
    return Vec3[T]{vec[0] + other[0], vec[1] + other[1], vec[2] + other[2]}
}

func (vec Vec3[T]) Mul(factor T) Vec3[T] {
    return Vec3[T]{vec[0] * factor, vec[1] * factor, vec[2] * factor}
}
```

I then wonder, what would an according constraint look like? Omitting the methods, I arrive at the following solution:

```golang
type Vec3ish[T constraints.Float] interface {
    ~[3]T
}
```

A function taking according arguments could look like so:

```golang
func addVecs[A Vec3ish[T], T constraints.Float](a, b A) A {
    return A{a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1], a[2] + b[2]}
}
```

This seems verbose. Is it really necessary to define both `T` and `A`?

Things get worse when we demand `Add` and `Mul` to be implemented:

```golang
type Vec3ish[T constraints.Float] interface {
    ~[3]T
}

type Vec3ishUseful[T constraints.Float, A Vec3ish[T]] interface {
    Vec3ish[T]
    Add(A) A
    Mul(T) A
}

func addVecsGeneric[U Vec3ishUseful[T, A], A Vec3ish[T], T constraints.Float](a U, b A) A {
    return a.Add(b)
}
```

An extra type, three generic type parameters, and having to give `a` and `b` separate types. Going further, I see no way to get the expression `a.Add(b).Add(b.Add(a))` to work within the function. This isn't the future I was hoping for. What needs to happen here?

Answer (score 1):

> This seems verbose. Is it really necessary to define both T and A?

Yes, it is.

Your interface `Vec3ish[T constraints.Float]` is itself parametrized, so you must instantiate it when using it as a constraint. Given the type constraint `A Vec3ish[T]` you can see that a function using it is also parametrized in `T`, and one `T` that fulfils the constraint in `Vec3ish` *at compile-time*.

The function declaration might look somewhat verbose, but at the call sites it will not, since type inference will do all the legwork:

```
v1 := Vec3[float64]{1, 2, 3}
v2 := Vec3[float64]{5, 6, 7}
result := addVecs(v1, v2)
```

Slightly less verbose would be to use the shorthand for the vector constraint, but if you plan to reuse the `Vec3ish` constraint, the named interface might be better:

```
func addVecs[A ~[3]T, T constraints.Float](a, b A) A {
    return A{a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1], a[2] + b[2]}
}
```

Same goes for the other interface, since there you want to capture both `T` and `A`, but again, at call site, it gets better:

```
addVecsGeneric(v1, v2)
```

One might think to use the parametrized interface *as type of the argument* and let type inference do the rest:

```
type Vec3ishUseful[T constraints.Float, A Vec3ish[T]] interface {
    Add(A) A
    Mul(T) A
}

// Instantiating Vec3ishUseful with type params T and A 
func addVecsGeneric[A Vec3ish[T], T constraints.Float](a Vec3ishUseful[T, A], b A) A {
    return a.Add(b)
}

// addVecsGeneric(v1, v2) doesn't compile
```

However this does not work (yet?). There's a quite extensive discussion about this [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41176). So by going this route, you have to let go of inference and pass the type parameters explicitly. This somewhat distributes verbosity between function signature and callers:

```
addVecsGeneric[Vec3[float64], float64](v1, v2)
```